# Add Edit Response Link to Email

Tags: google-apps-script

How do i add the "edit response link" to an email, i am using the script below, but was not sure if this is even possible

```
function myNotification(e) {
  if( e.values[10] == "FAIL" ) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(
       "email@jci.com",
       "Process Confirmation Audit Failure",
       "Please Review And Post Follow-Up Actions"
    ); 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Edit response link" but you can add HTML format to the emails with a slightly different use of `MailApp`. Like so:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(
   "email@cji.com",
   "Process Confirmation Audit Failure",
   "",
   {
      htmlBody: "Please revie... <br/> <a href='Link'>ResponseLink</a>"
   }
)
```

Comment: the "edit response link" is on the google forms after you submit form, it then shows a link to click onto to edit the form again

Comment: Ah I see.. I've just had a play with Google Forms and done a quick bit of Googling but it looks like that's not possible sorry.